# C++ How to create and use a pointer to find length of a character array?

Tags: c++, arrays

I want to find the length of the character array. I tried to create a pointer but it did not count anything. There is another part to the program where I need to capitalize the name which I already did. I know there is strlen but my instructions are to not use it.

```
const int SIZE = 25;   // Array size

int main()
{
    char name[SIZE+1] = "john smythe";  // To hold a name
    int length = 0; //for length of array

    //To get length of char name
    char *ptr = name; 
    ptr = new char; 
    while (*ptr != '\0')
    {
        length++; 
        ptr++;  `enter code here`
    }
    cout << "The length of the character is " << ptr++ << "." << endl; 

    cout << endl;
    system("PAUSE"); 
    return 0;
}
//end main
```

Comment: Lose the line `ptr = new char;`.

Comment: My output will still be something like...                                                     "John Smith .... The length of the character is."                                                   The numeric value of the length won't show still. I can do something like name[length] and exclude the pointer, but I have to user a pointer.

Comment: Don't do that. In C++, use `std::vector` (or `std::string` in your case)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have assigned `ptr` to `name`, there's no need to new it again. Delete this:

```
ptr = new char;
```

and you're not printing out the length of array, you should print out `length`:

```
cout << "The length of the character is " << length << "." << endl;
```

Comment: I deleted the ptr = new char and the cout statement. When I run the program, I just get the name but I need the length of the character array which does not show.

Comment: @Mary Don't delete the cout statement, just fix it like I posted. The length of the character array is stored in `length`, not `ptr`.

Comment: Okay. Thanks! It finally gave me the correct output.

Answer (score 0):

What you have is almost right. The idea is to scan through the string by incrementing a pointer looking for '\0'. The only major bug you have is that the while condition should be:

```
while (*ptr != '\0' && length < MAX_LENGTH)
```

You should rename SIZE to MAX_LENGTH and drop the +1's. If you don't stop at MAX_LENGTH what you have is known as a buffer overflow bug.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion. The program still runs fine with the pointer looking for the null character. The SIZE is defined as 25 to help with a prototype that I took out of the code.

Answer (score 0):

Your code is almost correct except you don't need to add the following line in your code -

```
ptr = new char;
```

And print the length instead of `ptr`. If I rewrite the code with these correction then it will be -

```
#include<iostream>
using namespace std;

const int SIZE = 25;  

int main()
{
    char name[SIZE+1] = "john smythe"; 
    int length = 0; 
    char *ptr = name;

    //ptr = new char;
    while (*ptr != '\0')
    {
        length++;
        ptr++;
    }
    cout << "The length of the character is " << length<< "." << endl;
    cout << endl;
    //system("PAUSE");
    return 0;
}
```

Hope it will help.
Thanks a lot.

Comment: Someone above already gave me the same corrections that I needed to fix the code. Thanks.